# Send email to all registered users

Tags: users, email, registered

I've got a about 60 registered users. How can I send an email out to all of them? Any suggestions on how to achieve this. The users have registered, so I don't think they are going to mind an email send to them, but how could I get that to work? would a plug in do what you said? send an email out to the registered users? or should I install a newsletter plug in and get everyone to sign up to that again/separately? I'm not looking for specific plug in names (although that would be handy) more how it works in theory?

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendations are off topic. Plugins are however the way to go here. There are a couple of plugins that you can achieve it with. Just do a quick google search for 'send email to users wordpress'

Comment: Plugin/Theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations). You could ask this on [Software Recommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress-plugin), the Google+ [WP Developers](https://plus.google.com/communities/101504763068635549461) group or [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you begin, you should know that sending mass emails is a delicate subject matter, and your hosting provider or mail provider has certain guidelines about this. Some hosting providers, such as Dreamhost, provide "Announcement Lists", which act as a platform for writing newsletters (or essentially emailing a large group of **subscribers**). Sending unsolicited email does not fall into this category, and you should approach with caution.

Probably the most barebone method of retrieving your users' email addresses would be to extract them from your WordPress database.

Running the following MySQL query will retrieve the user's login name in the first column, their chosen display name in the second, and their email address in the third. Using a spreadsheet, you could easily re-format all this information to your needs, such as creating a semi-colon separated string of emailaddress to use in the `Bcc:` header of your email.

`SELECT user_login, display_name, user_email FROM wp_users` provided that your tables prefix is `wp_` (consult your database or `wp-config.php` file if you are unsure).

The reason you would use the `Bcc:` field of your email is so that your users will not become aware of each other's email addresses. This is frowned upon as it is likely to cause more spam for them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Well the users have registered, so I don't think they are going to mind an email send to them, but how could I get that to work? would a plug in do what you said? send an email out to the registered users? or should I install a newsletter plug in and get everyone to sign up to that again/separately?

Comment: **Technically** speaking, a plugin could do this, but sending mass-email can be resource intensive (whether you or the plugin is using `wp_mail` or PHP's `mail`). But **practically** speaking, sending mass email without explicit consent from your users can get you into trouble. Also, sending mass email on your own merit (manual or through plugin) can trigger your provider's anti-spam alert. Your own email address could be blacklisted. I **strongly advise** using a newsletter service that suits your specific needs!